# How to add column to XML target definition in power centre

Tags: informatica

I have an already existing XML target in informatica power centre, but the file that was used to import this definition is missing.

I need to add one more tag to this target definition. I am aware of the “synchronise XML definition” option.

How would i approach this?

Comment: if you dont have xml definition - may be you can do - 1. export the target definition in xml. 2. Open using notepad++, add the new column with correct data type and in correct hierarchical position. 3. then reimport it back to infa and replace infa target definition. I am not 100% sure but i think this trick will work. do it in dev pls

Comment: But wouldn’t that result in changing the xml view which is already present?

Comment: you are going to change the xml target -isnt it ?

Comment: I want to add one more column to the existing target without changing the existing tags/view.

Comment: thats exactly what i said, change the target definition without definition. You are exporting the definition from infa (because you dont have it). and then changing it as per your need.